# I am getting Bad Request (400) messages for Emulated and REAL Azure storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am developing an Azure website, and I want to make use of Blob storage. I am using VS2013, Azure SDK 2.2. I have tried Azure Storage 2.1.0.4 from NuGet, I have tried using the latest 3.0.2.0 too. I have upgraded the emulator to the latest preview version 2.2.1, I was using 2.2.0 before.

My issue is, it doesnt matter if I point at the emulator or real storage, I get Bad Request 400 errors (invalid headers).

I set up a really simple form application, with a single button to make this easy.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

   CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

   CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("UserImages");    

   if (!container.Exists())
   {
      container.Create();
      container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off });
   }

}
```

Everything looks good until container.Exists() executes, and then I get an unhandled error (Bad Request 400). I have tried a few different operations and I get the same unhelpful message every time.

I am storing the Azure Connection string in the appSettings section, and in this simple example I have tried pointing at a real Storage Account, and the emulator, and I get the 400 error every time.

My config file has this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[MyAccountName];AccountKey=[MYREALKEY]" />
</appSettings>
```

Using the Server Explorer in VS2013, I can happily connect to both the Emulator and real storage, and access Blob storage without issue.

This is effectively stopping me adding the ability to my site to upload files to the storage account.

Anyone else having this problem? As far as I know, I have tried older versions and the latest versions of the important components. I have always had SDK 2.2 though.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

For information, I followed this example, which I found in the Azure management portal:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs-20/

Thanks

Ian

Comment: Please convert your container name to lowercase and retry your request.

Comment: can containers contains upper case letters? I thought they could not.

Comment: That fixed the issue for REAL storage, but the emulator still throws 400 errors. <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" /> is my Emulator string.

Comment: Is there any proper documentation I have missed, that seems like a schoolboy mistake, but I dont remember seeing rules on naming conventions etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This drove me insane for two days. Installing/Uninstalling the SDK, emulators, Azure Storage NuGet packages etc. I finally got the emulator working as well as real storage. The MSI you download to install the preview version of the emulator 2.2.1 contains a readme - I didnt know it was there, but it contains some pretty important instructions!

```
3. Copy all files from the following path:

        For 32-bit OS: "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Azure Storage Emulator 2.2.1\devstore"
        For 64-bit OS: "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Azure Storage Emulator 2.2.1\devstore"

   to the following path:

        "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\devstore"

   If prompted, choose to replace the existing files with the new ones.
```

It turns out the MSI doesnt update the files actually used by the emulator at run time! You have to perform this task by hand. I feel sooo stupid for not seeing this basic instruction. Turns out RTFM was the answer!

Answer (score 3):

To see naming rules, please check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135715.aspx. From this documentation page:

> A container name must be a valid DNS name, conforming to the following
>   naming rules:
>
> - Container names must start with a letter or number, and can contain    only letters, numbers, and the dash (-) character.
> - Every dash (-) character must be immediately preceded and followed by    a letter or number; consecutive dashes are not permitted    in
>     container names.
> - All letters in a container name must be lowercase.
> - Container names must be from 3 through 63 characters long.

Regarding getting 400 error with storage emulator, please check the storage client library version. If it's 3.x, then you would need to install storage emulator 2.2.1 released in preview today. More information about this can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/01/16/windows-azure-storage-emulator-2-2-1-preview-release-with-support-for-2013-08-15-version.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that, very useful. I got the latest preview emulator from that link you also provided 2.2.1 is/was installed, but the "about" menu option in the Emulator UI shows 2.2.0, so I might try that again.

Comment: You're correct about emulator version. If you notice the files under you have downloaded (under the `devstore` folder) using the link, they are all dlls and not the exe. This could be the reason why the emulator UI still shows version 2.2.0 and not 2.2.1. HTH.

Comment: Still not getting it working on the emulator. I removed with Add/Remove programs the old MSI package, and reinstalled this new one. I just tried this: <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://127.0.0.1;" />  Setting the DevelopmentStorateProxyUri explicitly. I tried http and https. I might be able to write the code I need pointing at real storage, but my unit tests might have to be disabled until I can fix this. the http/https is in the string, although my browser is hiding it now in this comment.

Comment: May I ask why are you setting this DevelopmentStorageProxyUri? This is useful when you want the requests to be routed through a proxy (e.g. Fiddler). Have to tried it with just `<add key="StorageConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true">`?

Comment: I started off with what you suggested, and I have been trying other examples I have seen on the forums. I noticed someone was using Fiddler with that additional setting, and some were using without mentioning fiddler. Figured it was worth a shot. Seems like a lot of effort to get the client talking to the emulator, and some suggest Fiddler is a workaround that is sometimes required, and other times its "fixed" and is not required.

Comment: I use the build and test agents in the cloud based TFS (tfspreview => visualstudio.com) to run my tests, so I was not intending to set up a fiddler solution as that will never work when the tests run on the remote agents.

Comment: Fiddler is helpful for diagnosing problems (like you're having) as it intercepts HTTP traffic. One last question: before you copied the files for SDK 2.2.1, did you stop the storage emulator?

Comment: I stopped the old one, uninstalled from add/remove programs and installed the new MSI. I didnt back up anything because there was nothing I wanted to keep, I was happy to get a clean start. I have rebooted as an extra precaution also.